# Is it normal for Nikon DSLR viewfinder and live view shutter speeds to differ?

Tags: nikon, exposure, shutter-speed, metering, live-view

I have a Nikon D600 set up on a tripod in a room with decent light.  I've tried using 2 different lenses & when I switch from the viewfinder to live view, and vice versa, the shutter speed is altering i.e. the exposure.  I'm in aperture priority mode, set fully open at the widest setting.

I've tried this with and without the viewfinder cover in place, as is suggested for live view, this makes no difference.

What I see:

```
live view:      50mm / f1.4 - 1/320 sec

view finder:    50mm / f1.4 - 1/500 sec
```

Looking at the images captured - the live view "version" looks more right to me.

Thank you in advance, I've searched and read other questions but they don't quite match my situation,  I'll check the manual too in case I've missed some setting.

One of the lenses I'm trying is brand new, so I don't think anything lens related is happening.

See also:

[Is it normal to see a different exposure reading through viewfinder and LCD?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/25943/34096)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a case of '*read the manual*'.

Page 54 - D600 manual.  Just posting in case any one else ponders this.

> **Exposure**
>
> Depending on the scene, exposure may differ from that which would be
>   obtained when live view is not used. Metering in live view is adjusted
>   to suit the live view display, producing photographs with exposure
>   close to what is seen in the monitor. In P, S, A, and M modes,
>   exposure can be adjusted by ±5 EV (0 112). Note that the effects of
>   values over +3 EV or under –3 EV can not be previewed in the monitor.